# What is the equivalent Query DSL object for the q parameter?

Tags: elasticsearch

When I `_search` on elasticsearch, sometimes I just query with a string like `q=NEEDLE` and let everything happen automagically, but when I want more complex queries I use a

```
{
  query:{ ... }
}
```

object.

I was wondering,

What would be the equivalent of sending the query string `q=NEEDLE` inside a Query DSL object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is equivalent to [Query String](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) . You can confirm this via the [code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/c7c8bb357a1ef459a7c59db4da9cbda1c0d439db/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/rest/action/support/RestActions.java#L99).
For the case in OP `"q=needle"` it is a `Query-String` run against `default_field`.

As per documentation this defaults to the index.query.default_field index settings, which in turn defaults to `"_all"`.

Example :

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {

           "query": "needle",
           "analyze_wildcard": false,
           "lenient" : false,
           "lowercase_expanded_terms" : true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you link to the documentation page please?

Comment: the document i was referring to is [query string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)  the option "default_field" explanation.